# How to get R7 through different choices in CLIPSIDE

Tags: clips

```
(defrule unable-to-diagnose
(name ?name)
(age ?age)
(gender ?gender)
    (temperature ?C)
            (or 
            (or (high-fever-days ?days)
               (and (vomiting no)
                 (abdominal-pain-or-diarrhea no)
                 (muscle-joint-pain no)
                 (sore-muscles-and-joints no)
                 (mild-conjunctival-congestion no))
               (and (shock no)
                 (respiratoty-failure no)
                 (hemoptysis-or-purulent-sputum no)
                 (shortness-of-breath)
                 (rales-can-be-heard-in-the-lungs no)))
               (abnormal-sneezing-or-runny-nose no))
=>          
(assert (diagnosis-result: unable-to-diagnose))
(printout t crlf "=======================================================================" crlf)
(printout t crlf "Diagnosis Result of " ?name " : unable-to-diagnose " crlf)
(printout t crlf "Treatment Suggestion to You :" crlf)
(printout t crlf "    " crlf)
(printout t crlf "=======================================================================" crlf))
```

//I think there should be a problem here, but I don’t know how to modify it.

---

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Oj3q.jpg)
There are 3 R7 here. How to get R7 through different choices?

Answer (score 0):

```
(defrule unable-to-diagnose
   (name ?name)
   (age ?age)
   (gender ?gender)
   (exists
      (temperature ?C)
      (or 
         (and 
            (test (>= ?C 39))
            (high-fever-days ?days)
            (or 
               (and 
                  (test (>= ?days 3))
                  (shock no)
                  (respiratory-failure no)
                  (hemoptysis-or-purulent-sputum no)
                  (shortness-of-breath no)
                  (rales-can-be-heard-in-the-lungs no)
               )                  
               (and
                  (test (< ?days 3))
                  (vomiting no)
                  (abdominal-pain-or-diarrhea no)
                  (muscle-joint-pain no)
                  (sore-muscles-and-joints no)
                  (mild-conjunctival-congestion no)
               )
            )
         )    
         (and
            (test (< ?C 39))
            (abnormal-sneezing-or-runny-nose no)
         )
      )
   )
   =>  
   (assert (diagnosis-result: unable-to-diagnose))
   (printout t crlf "=======================================================================" crlf)
   (printout t crlf "Diagnosis Result of " ?name " : unable-to-diagnose " crlf)
   (printout t crlf "Treatment Suggestion to You :" crlf)
   (printout t crlf "    " crlf)
   (printout t crlf "=======================================================================" crlf))
```